# Installing latest vtk on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, vtk

I am following [these commands](https://gist.github.com/planetceres/b33966cf2d5027f39c8d5998b65d26d2#file-install_pcl_vtk-sh-L48) on github to install vtk on my machine. I also installed all dependencies. When running `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/vtk-inst`, I get this error:

```
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Error: The source directory "/home/usr/usr/software/vtk/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

After this, I copied CmakeLists.txt into build directory, it says that:

```
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    VTKDetermineVersion


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    vtkVersion


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (determine_version):
  Unknown CMake command "determine_version".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/usr/usr/software/vtk/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake seems to think the build directory is the source directory.  You need to run CMake in the build directory and put the source directory as a command line argument.

For example, if the source directory is ~/vtk, and the build directory is ~/vtk-build you'd do something like this:

```
cd ~/vtk-build; cmake ~/vtk
```

So I am in vtk-build, and telling cmake the source directory is ~/vtk